# Find the limit of the mediant sequence $\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{ap_n+bk_n}{aq_n+bm_n},~\frac{k_{n+1}}{m_{n+1}}=\frac{cp_n+dk_n}{cq_n+dm_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, limits, proof-verification

How to find the general formula for the limit of the sequence:

$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{ap_n+bk_n}{aq_n+bm_n}$$

$$\frac{k_{n+1}}{m_{n+1}}=\frac{cp_n+dk_n}{cq_n+dm_n}$$

$$a,b,c,d>0$$

$$p_0,q_0,k_0,m_0>0$$

By the properties of the [mediant](http://mathpages.com/home/kmath055/kmath055.htm) we have the following set of inequalities (assuming $\frac{p_{0}}{q_{0}} \leq \frac{k_{0}}{m_{0}}$):

$$\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} \leq \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \leq \frac{k_{n}}{m_{n}}$$

$$\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} \leq \frac{k_{n+1}}{m_{n+1}} \leq \frac{k_{n}}{m_{n}}$$

This means that the sequence converges.

It is possilbe to find the $n$th term of the sequence:

$$\left( \begin{array}( p_n \\ k_n \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}( a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)^n \left( \begin{array}( p_0 \\ k_0 \end{array} \right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}( q_n \\ m_n \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}( a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)^n \left( \begin{array}( q_0 \\ m_0 \end{array} \right)$$

If the matrix is diagonalizable (which we assume), its eigenvalues will be:

$$\lambda, \mu=\frac{1}{2} \left(a+d \pm \sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)} \right)$$

Then the matrix raised to power $n$ [will be written as](https://xphysics.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/raising-the-power-of-a-2%C3%972-matrix/):

$$\left( \begin{array}( a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)^n=\frac{\lambda^n-\mu^n}{\lambda-\mu}\left( \begin{array}( a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)-\lambda \mu \frac{\lambda^{n-1}-\mu^{n-1}}{\lambda-\mu}\left( \begin{array}( 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Finally we obtain the general expression for the $n$th term of the sequence:

$$\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=\frac{(\lambda^n-\mu^n)(ap_0+bk_0)-\lambda \mu (\lambda^{n-1}-\mu^{n-1})p_0}{(\lambda^n-\mu^n)(aq_0+bm_0)-\lambda \mu (\lambda^{n-1}-\mu^{n-1})q_0}$$

The same goes for the other fraction, and their limits should be the same.

> Is the above correct? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?
>
> How to find the limit of the sequence (the general formula) in closed form:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}= ?$$

Obviously, it should be some quadratic irrational number (in general).

For example, numerical experiment suggests:

$$a=b=1,~~~~~c=2,~~~~d=3$$

$$p_0=q_0=m_0=1,~~~~~k_0=2$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}= 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

---

**Edit**

This idea just came to me: assume $\lambda> \mu$, then divide both numerator and denominator by $\lambda^n$. Then we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=\frac{ap_0+bk_0-\frac{\mu}{\lambda} p_0}{aq_0+bm_0-\frac{\mu}{\lambda}q_0}=\frac{\lambda(ap_0+bk_0)-\mu p_0}{\lambda(aq_0+bm_0)-\mu q_0}$$

> This appears to be wrong (see the above example). So where is my mistake?

---

**Edit 2**

Finally correcting the mistake above noticed by Peter Košinár:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=\frac{ap_0+bk_0-\mu p_0}{aq_0+bm_0-\mu q_0}$$

Since $\mu$ is the smaller of the eigenvalues and $a,b,c,d$ are positive we have:

$$\mu=\frac{1}{2} \left(a+d - \sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)} \right)$$

Or:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=\frac{(a-d+\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc})p_0+2bk_0}{(a-d+\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc})q_0+2bm_0}$$

See also comments from Wiley below to clarify the possible confusion about the definition of the sequence.

Comment: In your final evaluation of the limit: where did you get the factor $\frac{\mu}{\lambda}$ from? It looks more like a single $\mu$ to me.

Comment: @PeterKošinár, you are right, I incorrectly counted the exponents. What a waste of the bounty

Comment: @PeterKošinár, if you want the bounty, you can post your comment as an answer

Comment: @You'reInMyEye, also it looks like the recurrence from $n$ to $n+1$ is not uniquely defined.  Maybe you wanted to consider the fraction in lowest terms, e.g., $p_n$ and $q_n$ are coprime.  Otherwise one could multiply both of them by a random factor, which effectively change both $a$ and $c$.

Comment: @Wiley, take this as a shorthand. The quotient, I mean. We are to iterate two vectors and then take the quotient

Comment: @You'reInMyEye, so actually $p_{n+1}=ap_n+ck_n$ and $q_{n+1}=aq_n+cm_n$?

Comment: @Wiley, yes, that's correct. But I've only figured it out after first posting the question (even though in numerical experiments I stored $p_n$ and $q_n$ separately at each step)

Comment: @You'reInMyEye, that clears the confusion, thanks.  I agree with the solution you posted and what have been commented about the error.